# kill parent and child because endless loop

Tags: bash, kill, signals

I have a process run by cron every hour. Such process calls another one (not sourced), ie: `./childProc.sh` (Not sure if this detail is important)

Because of an endless loop in child process (which I'm still trying to find out why it does not end), I have to kill all processes related before run it again.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533377/why-child-process-still-alive-after-parent-process-was-killed-in-linux) and [this article (Kill PPIDs section)](http://riccomini.name/posts/linux/2012-09-25-kill-subprocesses-linux-bash/), but I don't understand the difference between: `kill -9 -$PPID`
and `kill -9 -- -$PPID`.

My questions are: 
What means here `--`? On the other hand, is `-9 (SIGKILL)` the right signal to kill a bash script process or is it too strong?

And lastly, my approach to check that behaviour (whether a process is still running) is creating a file that contains PID and PPID:

```
#!/bin/bash

# PID FILE 
PID_FILE="$BASE_BACKUP_DIR"/".pid.$HOSTNAME"; 

## If exists PID_FILE, kill 
if [[ -f "PID_FILE" ]]; then 
    pid_last=$(head -1 | cut -d " " -f1); 
    ppid_last=$(head -1 | cut -d " " -f2); 
    echoErr "Process is still running. Parent $ppid_last, child: $pid_last. "; 
    kill -9 -- -"$ppid_last"; 
fi;

## Create PID file
echo "$$ $PPID" > "$PID_FILE"; 

####### All process ####### 

# at the end, delete PID_FILE 
rm -f "$PID_FILE";
exit 0;
```

What do you think? Any improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `kill -9 -$PPID` and `kill -9 -- -$PPID`.

There *is* a difference between `kill -$PPID` and `kill -- -$PPID`. The `--` marks the end of option arguments: any argument after `--`, even if it begins with a `-`, will not be treated as an option. Without the `--`, the `-$PPID` will be treated as the signal to be sent.

IMHO SIGKILL is too strong. Start with SIGINT or SIGHUP instead, or the default, SIGTERM.

Comment: I'll take a look at the differences of each signal, although I think they all will work because I do not control any signal, nor it is run with `nohup` or any other command that captures signals. Thanks.